# Word2Vec vs Bert

Tags: машинное-обучение, word2vec

[Вопрос](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/362) про word2vec и bert. Приводится вот такой комментарий.

> One thing to realise is that word2vec provides context-free embeddings
>   (static) whereas BERT gives contextualised embeddings (dynamic). For
>   instance, take these two sentences "I like apples", "I like apple
>   MacBooks". Word2vec will give the same embedding for the word apple in
>   both sentences whereas BERT will give you a different one depending on
>   the context.
>
> Now coming back to your question, here is a step by step tutorial I
>   wrote to obtain contextualised embeddings from BERT:
>   https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-extract-contextualized-word-embeddings-from-bert-keras-tf-67ef29f60a7b

Вопрос. Почему автор утверждает, что `apple` в одном и в другом случае для word2vec будет не отличим? Могли бы Вы привести более подробный ответ. Насколько я понимаю, что проблема кроется в том, что w2v не умеет в мультиконтексты.

Comment: Здесь просто утверждается, что BERT учитывает контекст, Word2Vec же контекстонезависим.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Я это понимаю. Вопрос про пример, который приводит автор